# Ruby on rails complex select statement...there has to be a better way!

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I am building a query that could end up look like this:

```
SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients" 
INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "patients"."user_id" 
WHERE (users.username LIKE '%Bob%' AND users.last_name LIKE '%Smith%' 
AND users.active = '1' AND users.disabled = '1') 
ORDER BY users.first_name DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Below is code to create a complex query such as:

```
conditions = []
where = ''
where_parameters = []
order = 'users.last_name ASC'
per_page = 20

if is_admin?
  if defined?(params[:username]) and !params[:username].blank?
    where += 'users.username LIKE ? AND '
    where_parameters.push("%#{params[:username]}%")
  end

  if defined?(params[:last_name]) and !params[:last_name].blank?
    where += 'users.last_name LIKE ? AND '
    where_parameters.push("%#{params[:last_name]}%")
  end

  if defined?(params[:active]) and !params[:active].blank?
    where += 'users.active = ? AND '
    where_parameters.push(params[:active])
  end

  if defined?(params[:disabled]) and !params[:disabled].blank?
    where += 'users.disabled = ? AND '
    where_parameters.push(params[:disabled])
  end

  if !where.empty?
    where = where[0, where.length - 5]
    conditions = [where, *where_parameters]
  end

  if defined?(params[:order_by]) and !params[:order_by].blank?
    order = params[:order_by] + ' '
  end

  if defined?(params[:order]) and !params[:order].blank?
    order += params[:order]
  end

  if defined?(params[:per_page]) and !params[:per_page].blank?
    per_page = params[:per_page].to_i
  end
  @patients = Patient.joins(:user).paginate(:all, :include =>:user, :conditions => conditions, :order => order, :page => params[:page], :per_page => per_page)
```

Is there a better way to do this, this is just ugly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all be very careful when building queries from request data. When building your `where` string, you're using parametrized queries, so that's fine. But in your `order` string, you're building actual SQL code from data you directly take out of `params`. Do NOT do that. This is a big risk of SQL injection.

What you should do instead is take the order string apart (splitting at the comma), then check that each element is a column name optionally followed by `ASC` or `DESC`, then put the string back together accordingly.

A method for this could look something like this:

```
def safe_order_from_param(collection, order_string)
  tokens = order_string.split(/ *, */)
  tokens.each do |token|
    column, direction = token.match(/^(\w+)(? +(\w+))?$/).captures
    if Patient.column_names.include? column
      # if direction is nil, it will just be turned into the empty
      # string, so no problem there
      collection = collection.order("#{column} #{direction}")
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "No such column: #{column}"
    end
  end
end
```

---

Second of all `defined?(params[:foo])` does is check that `params` is defined. It does *not* check that `params` is a hash and has the key `:foo`. Since `params` will always exist, there really is no need for the check. Checking `params[:foo].blank?` is entirely sufficient.

---

Now to the main part of your question: the ugly building of the query string:

I assume from the fact that you're using the `joins` method that this is rails 3. In rails 3 options like `:include`, `:conditions` and `:order` are deprecated in favor of the corresponding query methods. The beauty of those methods is that they're chainable. So instead of building a query string using concatenation, it is much cleaner to just chain together multiple `where`s.

```
if is_admin?
  @patients = Patient.joins(:user).includes(:user).order('users.last_name ASC')

  unless params[:username].blank?
    @patients = @patients.where("users.username LIKE ?", params[:username])
  end

  # same for :last_name

  unless params[:active].blank?
    @patients = @patients.where("users.active" => params[:active])
  end

  # same for disabled

  unless params[:order_by].blank?
    @patients = safe_order_from_param(@patients, params[:order_by])
  end

  # same for order

  per_page = params[:per_page].blank? ? 20 : params[:per_page].to_i
  @patients = @patients.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => per_page)
end
```

Comment: Thank you! that was very helpful! What would I do in the case that I wanted to OR instead of AND? I guess I am probably in trouble...

Comment: @chris: Yes, if you want `OR`, you can't just chain `where`s. However you can still improve your string concatenation method by building an array instead of a string and then using `join(' OR ')` on it. That way you don't have to remove the trailing `OR` at the end like you're doing now with `AND`.